# SVG not working properly in IE9

Tags: html, css, svg, frontend

i'm having an issue with 3 SVG icons, and i don't know exactly why, because the same css is being apply in other icons, but they are working 100%.

The following problem is happening in IE9:

Chrome:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYfsb.png

IE9:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2220.png

In my search i found that i need add this metadata in the SVG tag:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
```

But didn't work.

The other icons is from fontastic

The codes:

1:

```
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="20px" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
          <path d="M340.377,292.154H227.178v-124.4h36v88.4h77.199V292.154z M389.404,378.858 c29.393-32.142,47.327-74.937,47.327-121.924c0-99.814-80.915-180.73-180.731-180.73c-99.815,0-180.73,80.916-180.73,180.73 c0,46.986,17.935,89.781,47.326,121.924c-9.047,22.51-20.913,52.037-28.938,72.002c-1.211,3.014-0.317,6.465,2.204,8.513 s6.086,2.219,8.786,0.413c18.391-12.305,45.747-30.606,65.463-43.797c25.548,13.824,54.801,21.677,85.889,21.677 s60.342-7.853,85.89-21.677l65.463,43.797c2.701,1.807,6.264,1.643,8.786-0.404c2.523-2.047,3.418-5.499,2.206-8.515 L389.404,378.858z M256,392.666c-75.013,0-135.73-60.707-135.73-135.731c0-75.013,60.706-135.73,135.73-135.73c75.013,0,135.731,60.704,135.731,135.73C391.731,331.945,331.026,392.666,256,392.666z M174.875,62.454c-12.251-7.292-26.556-11.491-41.848-11.491c-45.287,0-82,36.713-82,82c0,15.057,4.068,29.158,11.153,41.284C83.734,123.916,124.338,83.614,174.875,62.454z M449.82,174.246c7.085-12.126,11.152-26.227,11.152-41.283c0-45.287-36.713-82-82-82c-15.292,0-29.597,4.199-41.847,11.491C387.662,83.613,428.266,123.916,449.82,174.246z"></path>
        </svg>
```

2:

```
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="20px">
          <path d="M407.448,360.474c-59.036-13.617-113.989-25.541-87.375-75.717c81.01-152.729,21.473-234.406-64.072-234.406c-87.231,0-145.303,84.812-64.072,234.406c27.412,50.482-29.608,62.393-87.375,75.717c-59.012,13.609-54.473,44.723-54.473,101.176h411.838C461.919,405.196,466.458,374.083,407.448,360.474z"></path>
        </svg>
```

3:

```
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="20px" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
          <path d="M407.447,380.817c-50.919-11.622-112.919-41.622-94.652-80.682c11.732,19.236,48.084,30.361,76.4,13.736c-81.506-20.57,40.066-161.795-66.458-240.959c-38.877-29.041-95.209-29.373-133.474,0c-106.524,79.164,15.048,220.389-66.458,240.959c28.316,16.625,64.723,5,76.4-13.736c18.268,39.064-43.786,69.072-94.652,80.682c-59.041,13.475-54.473,52.025-54.473,80.176h411.838C461.919,432.843,466.489,394.294,407.447,380.817z"></path>
        </svg>
```

I don't believe this is a problem with the CSS, because the other icons is with the same style.

Comment: Please demo the actual issue in a JSfiddle.

Comment: hmm try deleting the xmlns attribute and version attribute , if not use them as images? :D when i used SVG i did not include the attribute xmlns and version and worked fine in IE for me

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a `height` or at least a `max-height`? It's hard to say without seeing the code for the page, but it looks like the SVG element is taller than it needs to be (with the image itself scaling down into the center based on the width you've applied).